# Horizontal Alignment of div with css background

Tags: html, css, alignment

i want to align a picture between two buttons inside a div

```
<div>
<button class="button">left</button>
<div class="picture">
<button class="button">right</button>  
</div>
```

this is what i have tried
http://jsfiddle.net/27YPH/

it works when i use an img tag for the image but gets messed up when i use the css-background propery to set the image

The image is a sprite so i dont want to use the img tag

now how do i place the div with the background between the 2 buttons?

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You do not have a closing div for `<div class="picture">`

Comment: ... and you will need to set dimensions (width/height) for the .picture element

Comment: @NathanLee sorry didnt see that. but it still doesnt align after closing the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. You do not have a closing div for `<div class="picture">`
You need to close that by `<div class="picture">&nbsp;</div>`

After that, you need to put a `height` and `width` for the class that contains the background image.

**For instance,**

```
.picture
{
    float:left;
    background:url("http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png") 0 0;
    width:128px; height:128px;


}
```

And then, you can get the image aligned.

Below is the demo.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/27YPH/2/)**

Hope this helps.

**ADD ON:**

If you want to vertically align you image, as per your code, below is the demo.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/27YPH/4/)**

Comment: thanks a lot. I was wrongly using self-closing div tags. That was my problem i guess.

Comment: Check for the **Add on for vertical alignment above as per your code**  - @user2878249